# How to recycle elememts when dimensions of two numpy arrays do not matches?

Tags: r, numpy, recycle

I would like to do something similar to the following `R` code with `numpy`, where `y` is recycled.

```
R> x=rbind(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
R> y=c(1,2)
R> x/y
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  2.0    3
[2,]    2  2.5    3
```

Obviously, the following code does not work with `numpy`. Does anybody know what is the equivalent python code that works? Thanks.

```
>>> x=numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> y=numpy.array([1,2])
>>> x/y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,)
```

Comment: Could you explain what's that R code doing?

Comment: It divides each column of `x` by `y`.

Comment: The title of your question is a bit confusing - what do you mean by "recycling y"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
x=numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6]])
y=numpy.array([1,2])
x/y[:, None]
```

`y[:, None]` turns the `(2,)` array to a `(2,1)` array, thereby allowing broadcast division with `x`.

Comment: Where is this feature documented?

Comment: @user1424739 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: @user1424739 Another source of information is here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html Note that `y[:, None]` is equivalent to `y[:, numpy.newaxis]`.